# SetValue makes dependencyProperty null

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I am trying to set a value on my dependency property but it always sets null.

```
[Description("Binded destination list"), Category("Data")]
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DestinationList", typeof(IEnumerable<TestEntity>), typeof(ListBoxEditLookup), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(IsDestinationListChangedCallback) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true, DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged});

public IEnumerable<TestEntity> DestinationList
{
     get { return GetValue(ItemsProperty) as IEnumerable<TestEntity>; }
     set
     {
          //After this line it becomes null
          SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
     }
}
```

When I check the value of value it is actually filled with values and of type `IEnumerable<TestEntity>`, but for some reason it says null! And when I set everything of type object instead of IEnumerable it works.

Comment: When are you checking the property? It may be null because you are checking it **too early**. Perhaps you can check it once the control has finished loading.

Comment: The control has loaded and I change the vallue when I check a box so that is not the problem. Also the initial value from the viewmodel is set the right way. It is only when I change the value inside the control that it is going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, because I binded with ObservableCollection, it cannot cast to IEnumerable

Comment: I have the same problem, and cast ObservableCollection to IEnumerable across AsEnumerable() saved me)